# Content rating for an app fetching medias from the Reddit API

Tags: android, google-play

I am coding an android app that **shows medias from a choosen subreddit** in a gallery format.

In the settings of the app I have a boolean value to allows fetching posts from **NSFW subreddits**.

To put my app on the **Play Store**, I had to answer the **Content Rating** form. Unfortunately my app was rejected 2 times, because "*The content rating was incorrect*".

I might understand it because the first time, I only answered "in a safe way", I just answered that sometimes my app shows mature content. They then told me that it was inappropriate because:

> For example, we found that your app contains Mature content.

The second time, I answered the form by saying that the app could contain **sex, drug references, nazi references, etc...** because this content exists on **Reddit**. They answered me this:

> For example, your app's current content rating is Adults only and that is not appropriate for your app. You need to choose your app's content rating lower than Adults only.

So, what do I do ? When I rate my app in a *chill* way, they are not okay and when I rate it in a *severe* way neither...

## So, what are the standards **Content rating policy** for the **The Reddit app**, or **any other Reddit clients** ?

Thanks for your future help. Below you can find the mails they answered me.
If you need to juge by yourself, I also can send you the APK.

### First email

> Hi David,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to the Google Play team.
>
> Status: Latest app update not available on Google Play
>
> During review, we found that the content rating is not accurate for your app. Content ratings are used to inform consumers, especially parents, of potentially objectionable content that exists within an app.
>
> For example, we found that your app contains Mature content.
>
> You can read through the Content Ratings policy page and Play Console Help Center article for more details. You may also want to check that your app complies with all other Developer Program Policies, as additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.
>
> Action required: Retake your app’s rating questionnaire
>   ...

### Second email

> Hi David,
>
> Thanks for contacting Google Play team.
>
> Status of latest updated app Gallereddit (com.ionic.gallereddit) not available on Google Play
>
> I’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that your app still violates Google Play Policy.
>
> Step 1: Fix the policy violation with your app
>
> During review, we found that the content rating is not accurate for your app. Content ratings are used to inform consumers, especially parents, of potentially objectionable content that exists within an app.
>
> We don’t allow apps that are assigned an incorrect content rating from the International Age Rating Coalition (IARC).
>
> For example, your app's current content rating is Adults only and that is not appropriate for your app. You need to choose your app's content rating lower than Adults only.
>
> You can read through the Content Ratings policy page and Play Console Help Center article for more details. You may also want to check that your app complies with all other Developer Program Policies, as additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.
>
> Action required: Retake your app’s rating questionnaire
>   ...

I already ask this question directly on the [androiddev subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/d9js0u/play_store_content_rating_for_an_app_fetching/).

Comment: I doubt you'll find answers for this here, there isn't much anyone here can do for you, it's between you and google and their terms of service

Comment: I hoped maybe a Reddit client developer might see this post and help me. Google is such not clear to explain what is going wrong...